# Can't determine my bounty amount

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

To reproduce this, go to a reputation page and look at a bounty award history.

This page of mine has one (the day that I obviously had to get a bounty): https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2015-01-20%2023:46:11Z&page=4

And it looks like this:

[image]

For some reason, the amount is in green, and the box is in "bounty blue". As you can see, its *impossible* to read.

Both of my bounties I checked this on were accepted as well, so that may have something to do with it. I believe that both bounties were manually awarded as well.

Comment: Rest is all white over green. Even on the bounties tab, it is white over blue. Beats me, why it is like this in this specific case. Perhaps, oversight.

Comment: @abhitalks Yeah, I can't think of any reason why the text would be green either.

Comment: Was that bounty awarded automatically or manually, if you remember that?

Comment: It is just a CSS selector that is bad, the one that sets the colour to white (for bounties) is being overridden by one setting it green for a positive rep change. [Here is what is happening using Firebug](http://imgur.com/tdJfTkm)

Comment: It isn't impossible to read the `+500`, it's just really hard.

Comment: @Bakuriu, It depends. For the most common type of color blindness, green is already super difficult to see. Therefore, having that shade of green on that shade of blue like that might be considered impossible for some to see. Also the color calibration of your screen could have an impact on readability as well.

Comment: It doesn't happen on the ["Time" Page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2015-01-20%2023:46:11Z) but it does happen on the ["Post" Page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2015-01-20%2023:46:11Z)

Comment: @Xan I believe that both were manual. Bakuriu, I'm not color blind, and even looking *closely* at it, I cannot determine what the text says (granted, I do have bad, corrected, vision to start with).

Comment: @Chrismas007 Very interesting, wonder why those are different!

Comment: I am not color-blind, but I can barely read it. I can read it barely on one of my monitors, and the other one it is completely illegible. Both are using a cool color balance.

Comment: SO is just trying to keep your math skills up: 595 - 50 - 35 - 10 = ?.

Comment: The designers were clearly Seahawk fans.

Answer (score 20):

This rule:

```
.user-show-new .user-rep-full .rep-up {
   color: #008000;
}
```

overrides this rule:

```
.bounty-indicator-tab {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #07d;
  padding: .2em .5em .25em .5em;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

So, the CSS will have to be changed to fix this bug.

Comment: it's `!important` that this gets fixed soon.

Comment: @CarrieKendall: Amusing, though the selector for the second rule's color specifications should probably should just be updated to `.bounty-indicator-tab, .bounty-indicator-tab .user-show-new .user-rep-full .rep-up`  Throwing `!important`s around can cause even more headaches long term.

Comment: Unfortunately, that explanation is entirely too long to pun with.

Answer (score 7):

I put a fix for this. the change will be on live after our next production build.

Comment: and when will it happen?